# Spaces not allowed Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, rest, http

```
RewriteEngine On
   ProxyPreserveHost on
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode 
RewriteRule ^/api/(.+)$ http://${HOSTNAME}:8080/api/$1 [P,NE]
```

Using this configuration I can have forward-slashes and back- slashes in url but no spaces.

```
/api/add/My/Name - ok
/api/add/My\name - ok
/api/add/My name - not ok
```

If I remove the NE flag, back-slashes and spaces work  but forward-slashes not.

```
/api/add/My/Name - not ok
/api/add/My\name - ok
/api/add/My name - ok
```

I know it's a bad practice to send strings with slashes and so on to REST but I can't do anything to change the current implementation at the moment...

Comment: First of all, you got “forward” and “backwards” ... well, backwards.  Secondly, what exactly does “not work” mean?

Comment: What part of your code is meant to deal with spaces?

Comment: @CBroe I get 404 error code for the url that doesn't work. They are blocked by Apache.